# javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures Question Unable to find answer

Tags: javascript

Assign the following three lines of text into the single variable myStr using escape sequences.

```
FirstLine
    \SecondLine
ThirdLine
```

You will need to use escape sequences to insert special characters correctly. You will also need to follow the spacing as it looks above, with no spaces between escape sequences or words.

Note: The indentation for SecondLine is achieved with the tab escape character, not spaces.

```
var myStr = "\nFirstLine\n\t\\SecondLine\nThirdLine";
```

Getting error: myStr should only contain characters shown in the instructions

Any suggestions why getting this error

Comment: Not sure if this would cause the error, but why does it _start_ with a `\n`? Did the instructions say anywhere, that there should be an empty line at the beginning ...?

Answer (score 0):

Remove \n before the first line, it will work.

Hope I answered your doubt!!
-Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myStr = "FirstLine\n\t\\SecondLine\nThirdLine";
```

Change this line.
It should work.